# Implementation of a directed graph

Tags: java, graph

I wrote an implementation of a directed graph using the adjacency list representation. My goal was to meet the big O requirements which I'd found [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type))

Please let me know about any drawbacks of the implementation.

```
package sample;

import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Set;

public class Graph<T> {

    private static final String EOL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    // Required: O(V + E)
    // Here it's O(V)
    private final Map<T, Node<T>> vertexes = new HashMap<>();
    private final Map<T, Set<Node<T>>> vertexesWithAdjacents = new HashMap<>();

    private Node<T> addVertexInternal(T key) {
        Node<T> node = vertexes.get(key);
        if (node == null) {
            vertexes.put(key, node = new Node<T>(key));
            vertexesWithAdjacents.put(key, null);
        }
        return node;
    }

    // Required: O(V)
    // Here it's O(1)
    public boolean areAdjacent(T first, T second) {
        if (vertexes.containsKey(first) && vertexes.containsKey(second)) {
            Set<Node<T>> firstAdj = vertexesWithAdjacents.get(first);
            Set<Node<T>> secondAdj = vertexesWithAdjacents.get(second);
            return firstAdj != null && vertexesWithAdjacents.get(first).contains(new Node<T>(second))
                    || secondAdj != null && vertexesWithAdjacents.get(second).contains(new Node<T>(first));
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Required: O(E)
    // Here it's O(1)
    public void removeVertex(T key) {
        vertexesWithAdjacents.remove(key);
        vertexes.remove(key);
    }

    // Required: O(E)
    // Here it's O(1)
    public void removeEdge(T from, T to) {
        vertexesWithAdjacents.get(from).remove(new Node<T>(to));
    }

    // Required: O(1)
    // Here it's O(1)
    public void addVertex(T key) {
        addVertexInternal(key);
    }

    // Required: O(1)
    // Here it's O(1)
    public void addEdge(T from, T to) {
        addVertexInternal(from);
        Node<T> toNode = addVertexInternal(to);

        Set<Node<T>> fromAdj = vertexesWithAdjacents.get(from);
        boolean newSet = false;
        if (fromAdj == null) {
            newSet = true;
            fromAdj = new HashSet<>();
        }
        fromAdj.add(toNode);
        if (newSet) {
            vertexesWithAdjacents.put(from, fromAdj);
        }
    }

    private void resetWhite() {
        for (T key : vertexes.keySet()) {
            vertexes.get(key).color = Color.WHITE;
        }
    }

    private void dfsInternal(Node<T> node) {
        if (node.color == Color.WHITE) {
            System.out.print(node + " ");
            // Actually we can set BLACK here.
            // GREY matters in hasCyclesInternal
            // See also http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9676/15063
            // and
            // http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9676/the-purpose-of-grey-node-in-graph-depth-first-search#comment140072_9681
            node.color = Color.GREY;
            Set<Node<T>> nodeAdj = vertexesWithAdjacents.get(node.key);
            if (nodeAdj != null) {
                for (Node<T> adj : nodeAdj) {
                    dfsInternal(adj);
                }
            }
            node.color = Color.BLACK;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (vertexesWithAdjacents.isEmpty()) {
            return "[]";
        }
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (T key : vertexesWithAdjacents.keySet()) {
            builder.append(key + ": " + vertexesWithAdjacents.get(key) + EOL);
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public void dfs() {
        if (!vertexes.isEmpty()) {
            resetWhite();
            dfsInternal(vertexes.entrySet().iterator().next().getValue());
        }
    }

    public boolean hasCycles() {
        if (!vertexes.isEmpty()) {
            resetWhite();
            return hasCyclesInternal(vertexes.entrySet().iterator().next().getValue());
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean hasCyclesInternal(Node<T> node) {
        if (node.color == Color.WHITE) {
            node.color = Color.GREY;
            Set<Node<T>> adjNodes = vertexesWithAdjacents.get(node.key);
            if (adjNodes != null) {
                for (Node<T> adj : adjNodes) {
                    if (adj.color == Color.GREY) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return hasCyclesInternal(adj);
                    }
                }
            }
            node.color = Color.BLACK;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static class Node<T> {

        T key;
        Graph.Color color;

        public Node(T key) {
            this.key = key;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return key.hashCode();
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return key.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj) {
                return true;
            }
            if (!(obj instanceof Node)) {
                return false;
            }
            Node<?> other = (Node<?>) obj;
            return key.equals(other.key);
        }

    }

    private enum Color {
        WHITE, GREY, BLACK
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Advice 1**

I would remove **`Node<T>`** and use **`T`** as the actual node type.

**Advice 2**

Also, I don't think it is worth maintaining **`vertexes`**; just use **`vertexesWithAdjacents`**. (By the way, the plural form of *vertex* is *vertices*.)

**Advice 3**

Since your graph is directed, it would make sense to make it explicit by renaming the graph to **`DirectedGraph`**.

**Advice 4**

In **`areAdjacent`** it looks like you don't obey the fact that the graph is directed: given an arc \$(u, v)\$ with no arc \$(v, u)\$, both will return **`true`** in **`areAdjacent`**.

**Advice 5**

I would remove the colors from each node and use a map from nodes to colors.

**Advice 6**

Furthermore, I would implement cycle detection algorithm and DFS as **not**  methods in the graph class.

**Finally**

You could take a look at [this implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/116686/simple-data-structures-for-representing-graphs-in-java).

Hope that helps.

Comment: I just posted a new implementation http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/151883/23821